# Android Device act like Server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I working on one project which Android device is act like a Server.  I mean, when I send any requests to my device, then I will get a response.

If any one have any idea so please tell me.  I am waiting for the reply.

Comment: have any idea of what? send request? receive request? flow of the sending/receiving?

Answer (score 2):

A server usually accepts request on a certain IP and Port. This is a problem for mobile devices, because usually they're on a private network (behind a router) and one can not address IP and port of a special device.

So, practically spoken, I really doubt that a mobile device can act as a server.

---

A reliable solution would require some sort of extra proxy server. Basically your mobile will connect with this "ground-based" server and the system of proxy and handheld is *the* server you're looking for. It is operational once the handheld is connected. Client establish connection with the proxy and send their requests, the proxy forwards the request to the mobile device to get a service response for the client.

A nice architecture for this approach is XMPP, the implementation of the proxy server would be a standard xmpp server (like *openfire*).